# Javascript does not work in Opera - strange

Tags: javascript, opera

have a javascript code to exec on a page - all works fine in Firefox, IE, Chrome but does not work in Opera 10+.

Strange is that this javascript works fine in previous versions of Opera (9.xx is fine) and even more strange is that when I lunch Dragonfly on Opera 10+ the javascript works also fine (and Dragonfly does not throw any errors).

Have anyone experienced this behavior and found any solution/workaround?

As the js code is quite complicated, huge and part of it dynamically generated I am not posting any sample of it - my question is just about the behavior and if someone has any experiencies with debuging/resolving.

Thanks,

Jan

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a bug in Opera's Just In Time (JIT) compilation. I assume that it worked in 10.10 but broke in 10.50 and above. Does it work if you disable this option: opera:config#jit ?

I would very much appreciate a bug report with code - https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/ . If you report the bug number here I can follow up a little bit faster :).

Answer (score 0):

Check this Tools..Preferences..Advanced..Content..Javascript options

Or tools..Quick preferences..ensure "enable Javascript checked"

Or you have overridden these with site preferences or user mode stuff.

I'm typing this in Opera 10.60 with no problems, admittedly not as developer or with Dragonfly running

Answer (score 0):

Try: Tools -> Advanced -> Error Console