# Javascript is not working in Opera

Tags: javascript, opera

I know this is an old question but before you dismiss it, just here me out.

I am developing a site and everything (including javascript) works perfect in Firefox 24.0 and Chromium 28.0. I have not tested in IE coz am on an Ubuntu 13.04 machine. I tested in Opera 12.16 and suddenly my javascript doesn't work.

Javascript is checked in opera preferences and all my external jquery and javascript scripts have the type="text/javascript" part. Still no good. I have commented out all my external script files including jquery and then added a
`<script type="text/javascript"> alert('JS working'); </script>` 
in the head. Still no good. Alert working in Firefox and Chrome but not in Opera.

I have checked these questions out, still no good:

- [javascript not working in OPERA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938744/javascript-not-working-in-opera)
- [Javascript does not work in Opera - strange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211546/javascript-does-not-work-in-opera-strange)

I don't know what's going on with Opera and its really confusing.
Any help appreciated.

**Update:**
There are no javascript errors in the dragonfly error console.

Comment: Have you tried testing js using a very, very simple test page? Have you tested you real page using Opera on a different computer?

Comment: @Jeffman The alert is working on a very simple page with just a H1 title and lipsum paragraph. Atleast I know javascript is working, now to know why it ain't working on my site. I only have one computer so the second option ain't possible.

Comment: @Jeffman Wow, I have just cleared ALL my private data in **Tools->Delete Private Data** and checked everything. Now my Javascript is working again. I don't know what had happened but am glad it's working now. Thanks.

Comment: Normally Opera would cache the pages along with their scripts, so any subsequent changes will not work, as they don't exist for Opera, until you clear the browsing data.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like JS is disabled in Opera. Pless and select Enable Javascript.

Comment: JS wasn't disabled. That was the first thing I checked. Like in my comments above, it worked in a very, very simple test page but wasn't working in my site. After clearing all my private data (history, cache, cookies, etc) it worked again. Can't explain it myself but that whats happened. Thanxs for the help, appreciated.